# How can I get a NSMenuItem from a submenu?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I have a reference to the outermost menu, but I'm trying to get a reference to an NSMenuItem that's nested in a submenu:

```
NSMenuItem* file_menu = [menu itemWithTitle:@"File];
```

file_menu is obviously a submenu (NSMenu), but I'm not sure how to get an item out of it's itemarray. I've tried casting it to an NSMenu and performing itemWithTitle as a selector with no luck.

How can I get the first NSMenuItem out of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this.

```
NSMenuItem* file_menu = [menu itemWithTitle:@"File"];
if (file_menu.hasSubmenu) {
    NSArray *menu_items = file_menu.submenu.itemArray;
    NSMenuItem *first_item = [menu_items objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

If the menu item has a sub menu the submenu property will let you access it, you can then access its menu items using the itemArray property.