# How can I get the title of a NSMenuItem in a submenu of a NSPopUpButton?

Tags: swift, macos

I can get the name of a `NSMenuItem` at the top level of the `NSMenu` of a `NSPopUpButton`.

I do this by adding an action to the `NSPopUpButton`:

```
@IBAction func menuDropdownAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let titleOfSelectedItem = (sender as AnyObject).titleOfSelectedItem

    print (titleOfSelectedItem! as Any)
}
```

But if I add a submenu to the `NSMenu` it just returns `nil`.

It seems to me that `.titleOfSelectedItem` applied to the `NSPopUpButton` should work for items buried in its submenus, but it seems not!

Any assistance would be gratefully accepted, there is a similar question, but its over 10 years old for cocoa and was no use to me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853929/how-can-i-get-a-nsmenuitem-from-a-submenu)

Comment: "was no use to me" Why not? Just get the submenu items.

Comment: Hi Leo, I tried   " let selectedItemSubmenu = (sender as AnyObject).submenu" but this returns nil. any idea?

Comment: try casting `as NSMenuItem`. Make sure that the sender is a menu item and that it is the one that contains a submenu.

Comment: `titleOfSelectedItem` is a method of `NSPopUpButton`. Is this the action method of a `NSPopUpButton`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Willeke, I have a NSPopUpButton and I want to return the titleOfSelectedItem, the code in the question works fine for items at the top level, but items in sub menus don't return anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display selected sub-menuItem in NSPopUpButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779015/display-selected-sub-menuitem-in-nspopupbutton)

Comment: Is the pop-up button in [Drop Down](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/pull-down-buttons/) mode?

Comment: There are two types I can define, pull down, and pop up. Its currently set to pop up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift is a strong typed language and you don't care about the type by writing `Any` and `AnyObject`.

Replace the `sender` with the **real** type

```
@IBAction func menuDropdownAction(_ sender: NSPopUpButton) {
```

then you can access all properties of the popup button

```
    let titleOfSelectedItem = sender.titleOfSelectedItem
    let menu = sender.menu!
    let firstMenuItem = menu.item(at: 0)!
    let subMenu = firstMenuItem.submenu!
```

Comment: Thank you, defining the type makes sense.  FYI last line should end with submenu! with lowercase M

Comment: What is the title of the selected item in the submenu?